# How to make line between each category on menu small thin?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app display Report categories on left side menu I face Issue border bottom between every

category and category below is more big so I need border small thin .

I work on [stackbliz](http://%20%20%20%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-1arrvm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) sample

what I try to change on css

```
.sideNav > li:first-child {
    border-top: 3px #e5e5e5 solid red;
  }
```

I make `3px` to `0px` but nothing changed on design .

also I try on html change this

```
<ul *ngFor="let rep of allReportCategories;let i = index;"  style="margin-top:2px;" 
    class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" 
    data-slide-speed="200">
```

I change `margin-top :2px` to `0px` but nothing changed on design .

So what I do to make border small size .

Menu I desired after border be small image that have red lines below .

Border must be thin not big

**Updated Post :**

```
<li class="active open">
```

when remove line above from html border removed and left border also remove

I need to make border bottom thin not thick

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of `:after` that exists, I removed it and added a padding-bottom, it looks like it worked:

[image]

I removed and added this codes to CSS:

```
/* Removed
.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}
*/

/* Added */
.active.open{
  padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

The stackblitz working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-tym4bg?file=app/app.component.css

I hope I helped you!

Comment: exactly this is what I need

Comment: I need also small thing if possible I need hover to be same size of cell

Comment: I updated the example I gave, but it was not simple, you repeat the id="menu" several times, there can only be a single id on the page, I removed that id and changed it to a class="menu", but I don't know if this will interfere with something in your code, you need to adjust it and see if it works together with the rest of the application, otherwise you will have to change the rest as well

Comment: The hover was in the wrong place, it was supposed to be on the #menu, so I switched to a class and it stayed that way: .menu{
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .menu:hover, .menu:hover .accordion{
    background-color: #ccc!important;
}

Comment: it solved thanks but remaining one thing please sub category I need to increase heigh of every cell as example DahsboardParametric - MainCompliance I need to increase heigh of sub category MainCompliance so how to increase height of every cell from sub category

Comment: if you see above SW Test i need to increase Height of every cell from subcategory

Comment: if you can help me on that please